# Complex join of longitudinal tables in R

Tags: r, join, dplyr, tidyr

I have ~16 .txt files that I need to turn into one, wide flat file. For each new file, time has passed, and some new variables are added. What I would like to do is append those new columns to the right side of the first table, joining by an identification variable. This gets complicated quickly, so here is an MRE:

```
library(dplyr)

id <- as.character(1:6)
first <- c("jeff", "jimmy", "andrew", "taj", "karl-anthony", "jamal")
last <- c("teague", "butler", "wiggins", "gibson", "towns", "crawford")
set.seed(1839)
a <- c(1:4, NA, NA)
b <- c(1:4, NA, NA)
c <- c(11:13, NA, 14, NA)
d <- c(11:13, NA, 14, NA)
e <- c(21, 22, NA, 24, NA, 26)
f <- c(21, 22, NA, 24, NA, 26)
```

Simulating the three different files:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  id = id[c(1:3,5)],
  first = first[c(1:3,5)],
  last = last[c(1:3,5)],
  a = a[c(1:3,5)],
  b = b[c(1:3,5)]
)

df_2 <- data.frame(
  id = id[c(1:3,5)],
  first = first[c(1:3,5)],
  last = last[c(1:3,5)],
  c = c[c(1:3,5)],
  d = d[c(1:3,5)]
)

df_3 <- data.frame(
  id = id[c(1,2,4,6)],
  first = first[c(1,2,4,6)],
  last = last[c(1,2,4,6)],
  e = e[c(1,2,4,6)],
  f = f[c(1,2,4,6)]
)

df_goal <- data.frame(id, first, last, a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

`df_goal` is what I want, and here is what it looks like:

```
> df_goal
  id        first     last  a  b  c  d  e  f
1  1         jeff   teague  1  1 11 11 21 21
2  2        jimmy   butler  2  2 12 12 22 22
3  3       andrew  wiggins  3  3 13 13 NA NA
4  4          taj   gibson  4  4 NA NA 24 24
5  5 karl-anthony    towns NA NA 14 14 NA NA
6  6        jamal crawford NA NA NA NA 26 26
```

Note that these are very big files, and the columns are not always in the right order, so I cannot just say to join by keeping the first three columns.

If I do a `full_join` on all, I get the names repeated every time:

```
df_all <- df_1 %>% 
  full_join(df_2, by = "id") %>% 
  full_join(df_3, by = "id")

> df_all
  id      first.x  last.x  a  b      first.y  last.y  c  d first     last  e  f
1  1         jeff  teague  1  1         jeff  teague 11 11  jeff   teague 21 21
2  2        jimmy  butler  2  2        jimmy  butler 12 12 jimmy   butler 22 22
3  3       andrew wiggins  3  3       andrew wiggins 13 13  <NA>     <NA> NA NA
4  5 karl-anthony   towns NA NA karl-anthony   towns 14 14  <NA>     <NA> NA NA
5  4         <NA>    <NA> NA NA         <NA>    <NA> NA NA   taj   gibson 24 24
6  6         <NA>    <NA> NA NA         <NA>    <NA> NA NA jamal crawford 26 26
```

What I tried to do next. I wrote a `for` loop, and I got each data frame, selected just (a) the `id` column, and (b) columns whose names have not appeared in the `df_all` data frame yet, and (c) did a `full_join`:

```
dfs <- c("df_2", "df_3")
df_all1 <- df_1
for (i in dfs) {
  df_all1 <- get(i)[!names(get(i)) %in% names(df_all1)[-1]] %>% 
    full_join(df_all1, .)
}

> df_all1
  id        first    last  a  b  c  d  e  f
1  1         jeff  teague  1  1 11 11 21 21
2  2        jimmy  butler  2  2 12 12 22 22
3  3       andrew wiggins  3  3 13 13 NA NA
4  5 karl-anthony   towns NA NA 14 14 NA NA
5  4         <NA>    <NA> NA NA NA NA 24 24
6  6         <NA>    <NA> NA NA NA NA 26 26
```

Note that this means the cases that did *not* appear in the first file are missing the names (these represent key demographic variables in my data). I also tried going through row-by-row and doing a column join if the `id` was already present, and then doing a `bind_row` if it was not. This code threw an error:

```
df_all2 <- df_1
for (i in dfs) {
  for (k in 1:nrow(get(i))) {
    if (get(i)[k, "id"] %in% df_all2$id) {
      df_all2 <- get(i)[k, !names(get(i)) %in% names(df_all2)[-1]] %>% 
        left_join(df_all2, ., by = "id")
    } else {
      df_all2 <- bind_rows(
        df_all2,
        get(i)[k, !names(get(i)) %in% names(df_all2)[-1]]
      )
    }
  }
}
```

There has *got* to be a way to do a `join` with only select columns, but fill in missing information if necessary. Again, I am working with lots of files with lots of columns, so I cannot assume that I know the position of any columns; it has to be done by the column names.

I have also thought about just including a new variable that is the date of the file, stacking them all on top of one another ("long" format), and then using `tidyr::spread` and `tidyr::gather`, but I haven't found a solution yet.

I am not wedded to the `tidyverse` (`base` or `data.table` would be great, even some way to do a SQL join in R) or even R; I am open to a Python solution using pandas, as well.

**Short version:** How do I join new columns to an existing data set—by identification number—and fill in information from not-new columns, but since the case is new, need to be filled in?

---

**Possible solution, per Psidom:**

```
df_all1 <- df_1
for (i in dfs) {
  df_all1 <- get(i) %>% 
    full_join(
      df_all1, ., 
      by = names(get(i))[names(get(i)) %in% names(df_all1)]
    )
}
df_all1
```

Maybe a more efficient way to do this, though?

Comment: I totally skipped over including where I defined those data.frames. Updated now.

Comment: `df_1 %>% full_join(df_2, by = c("id", "first", "last")) %>%  full_join(df_3, by = c("id", "first", "last"))` works for me.

Comment: Me too, thanks! But: What if I don't know the names of those variables? That is, let's say I want to join by all of the variables that the "omnibus" data frame has up to thus far?

Comment: I wonder if you can do that. Is the id unique within each file? If it is, then probably you want this. `bind_rows(list(df_1, df_2, df_3)) %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_all(funs(na.omit(.)[1]))`.

Comment: I added a possible solution, based on yours, that doesn't require me to know all the variables that the data frames share. Thoughts on that?

Comment: Yes, the `id` is unique within each file and refers to one person across all files.

Comment: That will create duplicated ids, if some attributes don't match. Not sure if that is what you need.

Comment: You are correct. Will your `bind_rows` / `group_by` / `summarise_all` solution get around that problem, though?

Comment: Yes. If there are conflicts, it takes the value that comes first from the list of data frames.

Comment: That is incredible. I assume that the `[1]` is responsible for choosing the first one? I need to look into more how `na.omit()` works, because it's bothering me how I don't know how that last line works.

Comment: `na.omit` simply drops all `NA` values in a vector. So `na.omit(.)[1]` takes the first non NA value, unless all are NAs, in which case it returns NA as well.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using `melt` once you have a `full_join` df_all.

```
library(data.table)
df <- melt(setDT(df_all), 
 measure.vars = patterns("^first", "^last"))
df <- unique(df[,-c("id", "variable")])
df[!is.na(df$value1),]

    a  b  c  d  e  f       value1   value2
1:  1  1 11 11 21 21         jeff   teague
2:  2  2 12 12 22 22        jimmy   butler
3:  3  3 13 13 NA NA       andrew  wiggins
4: NA NA 14 14 NA NA karl-anthony    towns
5: NA NA NA NA 24 24          taj   gibson
6: NA NA NA NA 26 26        jamal crawford
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution using `dplyr` is to omit the `by` parameter in the calls to `full_join()`.

```
library(dplyr)
df_1 %>% 
  full_join(df_2) %>% 
  full_join(df_3)
```

> Joining, by = c("id", "first", "last")
>   Joining, by = c("id", "first",
>   "last")
>
> ```
>   id        first     last  a  b  c  d  e  f
> 1  1         jeff   teague  1  1 11 11 21 21
> 2  2        jimmy   butler  2  2 12 12 22 22
> 3  3       andrew  wiggins  3  3 13 13 NA NA
> 4  5 karl-anthony    towns NA NA 14 14 NA NA
> 5  4          taj   gibson NA NA NA NA 24 24
> 6  6        jamal crawford NA NA NA NA 26 26
> ```
>
> Warning messages:
>   1: Column `id` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
>   2: Column `first` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
>   3: Column `last` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector

The documentation of the `by` parameter in `?full_join` says: *If `NULL`, the default, `*_join()` will do a natural join, using all variables with common names across the two tables.*

So this is equivivalent to explicetely passing `by = c("id", "first", "last")` [as proposed by Psidom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498633/complex-join-of-longitudinal-tables-in-r/46502485#comment79952361_46498633).

---

If there are many data frames to join, the code below may save a lot of typing:

```
Reduce(full_join, list(df_1, df_2, df_3))
```

The result (inluding messages) is the same as above.